# Best way to compare data from file to data in array in Matlab

Tags: file, matlab, io

I am having a bit of trouble with a specific file i/o in matlab, I am fairly new to it still so some things are still a bit of a mystery to me. The input file is structured as so:

```
File Name: Processed_kplr003942670-2010174085026_llc.fits.txt
File contents- 6 Header Lines then:
                1, 2, 3
                1, 2, 3
basically a matrix of about [1443,3] with varying values
```

now here is the matrix that I'm comparing it to:

```
[(0123456, 1, 2, 3), (0123456, 2, 3, 4), (etc..)]
```

Now here is my problem, first I need to know how to properly do the file input in a way which can let me compare the ID number (0123456) that is in the filename with the ID value that is in the matrix, so that I can compare the other columns of both. I do not know how to achieve this in matlab. Furthermore, I need to be able to loop over every point in the the matrix that matches up to the specific file, for example:

If I have 15 files ranging from 'Processed_0123456_1' to 'Processed_0123456_15' then I want to be able to read in the values contained in 'Processed_0123456_1'and compare them to ***ANY*** row in the matrix that corresponds to that ID (0123456). I don't know if maybe accumaray can be used for this, but as I said I'm not sure.

```
So the code must: 
-Read in file
-Compare file to any point in the matrix with corresponding ID
-Do operations
-Loop over until full list of files in the directory are read in and processed, and output a matrix with the results.
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Exact File Sample--

```
Kepler I.D.-----Channel

[1161345]--------[84]

-TTYPE1--------TTYPE8------------TTYPE4

['TIME']---['PDCSAP_FLUX']---['SAP_FLUX']

['BJD - 2454833']--['e-/s']--------['e-/s']

CROWDSAP --- 0.9791

630.195880143,277165.0,268233.0
630.216312946,277214.0,268270.0
630.23674585,277239.0,268293.0
630.257178554,277296.0,268355.0
630.277611357,277294.0,268364.0
630.29804426,277365.0,268441.0
630.318476962,277337.0,268419.0
630.338909764,277403.0,268481.0
630.359342667,277389.0,268463.0
630.379775369,277441.0,268508.0
630.40020817,277545.0,268604.0
```

There are more entries than what was just posted but they go for about 1000 lines so it is impractical to post that all here.

Comment: What do you mean by "ID value that is in the matrix" and "every point in the the matrix that matches up to the specific file"? Can you give a concrete example? Do you mean that you need to somehow concatenate all files with the same ID number and then search them?

Comment: What I mean is that if the file ID is 12345, and the matrix that im comparing it with has any row with column 1 equal to that ID value, then it should designate that row as the 'working' row for me to pull in the other column values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the file ID, use regular expressions, e.g.:

```
filename = 'Processed_0123456_1';
file_id_str = regexprep(filename, 'Processed_(\d+)_\d+', '$1');
file_num_str = regexprep(filename, 'Processed_\d+_(\d+)', '$1')
```

To read in the file contents, assuming that it's all comma-separated values without a header, use textscan, e.g.,

```
fid = fopen(filename)
C = textscan(fid, '%f,%f,%f') % Use as many %f specifiers as you have entries per line in the file
```

textscan also works on strings. So, for example, if your file contents was:

```
filestr = sprintf('1, 2, 3\n1, 3, 3')
```

Then running textscan on `filestr` works like this:

```
C = textscan(filestr, '%f,%f,%f')
C = 
    [2x1 int32]    [2x1 int32]    [2x1 int32]
```

You can convert that to a matrix using cell2mat:

```
cell2mat(C)
ans =
           1           2           3
           1           3           3
```

You could then repeat this procedure for all files with the same ID and concatenate them into a single matrix, e.g.,

```
C_full = [];
for (all files with the same ID)
  C = do_all_the_above_stuff;
  C_full = [C_full; C];
end
```

Then you can look for what you want in `C_full`.

**Update based on updated OP Dec 12, 2013**

Here's code to read the values from a single file. Wrap this all in the the loop that I mentioned above to loop over all your files and read them all into a single matrix.

```
fid = fopen('/path/to/file');

% Skip over 12 header lines
for kk = 1:12
  fgetl(fid);
end

% Read in values to a matrix
C = textscan(fid, '%f,%f,%f');
C = cell2mat(C);
```

Comment: I neglected to put this in the OP but the text file does have delimiters, how would I account for that? And does using C = .... multiple times update the value of C each time I re-assign it?

Comment: You put the delimiters explicitly in the textscan format specifier line. In the line I gave you, `textscan(fid, '%f,%f,%f')`, it assumes that a comma is the delimiter. I believe that whitespace is ignored. And yes, every time you do `C = ...`, the old value of `C` is lost. That's why I concatenated onto a new matrix, `C_full`, in each iteration.

Comment: I'm sorry I feel like an idiot I meant header lines for the input file, I understand the comma delimiters.

Comment: If you know how many header lines the file has, you can skip them using [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html). Open the file and first run `fgetl(fid)` once per header line (ignoring the output). This will move the file pointer past the header. *Then* run `textscan`.

Comment: Hey I'm still having a hard time with the textscan, my files are formatted exactly as shown in the OP but when i run that in the command window for an open file it gives me a [0x1] double matrix, so essentially an empty matrix, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post an example file?

Comment: I went ahead and added a sample file, there are around 1700 or so similar files.

Comment: I just need one last bit of help, as I am having problems with finding how to change the regexp you set up, the exact setup of the filenames is Processed_kplr003942670-2010174085026_llc.fits.txt, I would really appreciate getting some help with adjuting it

Comment: What is the number do you want to extract from that filename?

Comment: I need just the 3942670, not including the leading 00

Comment: Assuming `filename` is a string with your filename, `file_num_str = regexprep(filename, '[a-zA-Z_]+(\d+).*', '$1')`. Then, `file_num_str` will be a string with the file number, including the leading zeros. If you convert `file_num_str` to a number, e.g., via `str2double`, the leading zeros will automatically by stripped. You could also explicitly ignore leading zeros using the regular expression `regexprep(str, '[a-zA-Z_0]+(\d+).*', '$1')` (notice I added a zero inside the square brackets).

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirements are too complicated to write the whole script here. Nonetheless, I will try to give some pointers to help. Disclaimer: None of this is tested, just my best guess. Please expect syntax errors, etc. I hope you can figure them out :-)

1) You can use the [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function with the `delimiter` option to get data from the lines of your file. Since your format varies as it does, we will probably want to use...

2) ... [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to read the first two lines into strings and process them separately using `texstscan`. Such an operation might look like:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','w');
tline1 = fgetl(fid);
tline2 = fgetl(fid);
fclose(fid);
C1 = textscan(tline1,'%s %d %s','delimiter','_'); %C1{2} will be the integer we want
C2 = textscan(tline2,'%s %s'),'delimiter,':'); %C2{2} will be the values we want, but they're still a string so...
mat = str2num(C2{2});
```

3) Then, for the rest of the lines, we can use something like [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html):

```
mat2 = dlmread('file.txt',',',2,0);
```

The `2,0` specifies the offset in 0-based `rows,columns` from the start of the file. You may need to look at something like [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) to stitch `mat` and `mat2` together.

4) The list of files in the directory can be found with the [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) command. The filename is an attribute of the structure that's returned:

```
dirlist = dir;
for i = 1:length(dirlist)
    filename = dirlist(i).name
    %process your files
end
```

You can also pass matching strings to `dir`, like so:

```
dirlist = dir('*.txt');
```

which will find all of the files with extension `.txt`.

5) You can very easily loop through the comparison matrix:

```
sze = size(comparisonmatrix);
for i = 1:sze(1)
    %compare comparisonmatrix(i,1) to C1{2}
    %Perform whatever operations you need
end
```

Hope that helps!